# Reset a socket connection in python without cancelling the script

Tags: python, sockets, reset, netcat

I have a server in python that receiving data (I'm using some sockets). I want to reset a connection in order to be able to connect again the socket with the same IP.

I send data with this command with netcat :
`nc 192.168.8.21 12345 < data.txt`

And here is the script of my server

```
HOST = '192.168.8.21'  
PORT = 12345        

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data.decode('ascii'))
```

I tried to closed the socket. But the script is cancelling and I need to restart it.

If you have some ideas, thanks !

Comment: Are you willing to correct the `nc` invocation?

Comment: yes that's it. In all case I have a nc connection, and I need to create a proxy to catch the information sended by netcat

Comment: I was asking if you want to keep the `nc` command as you wrote it, or are willing to add a required option.